# Where Clause with And & Or

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to add an Or clause to my where statement and could use a little help.

Here's what I have:

```
  Where
  W.Insured_Id = P.Insured_Id and
  P.Insured_Id = I.Insured_Id and
  I.Insured_Id = IU.Insured_Id and
  p.expiration_date > to_date ('30-Apr-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  p.expiration_date < to_date ('16-Dec-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') or      
  p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-May-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  p.annual_premium < '1000' or
  p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-Jan-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  p.annual_premium < '1000'
```

I am trying to return all policies between May 1st and December 15 and only the policies that have less than 1000 in premium for the remainder of the year.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a bit confusing because your code suggests you're trying to do something very different than what you're asking. To accomplish what you've asked, you'll want to do something along the lines of :

```
Where
W.Insured_Id = P.Insured_Id and
P.Insured_Id = I.Insured_Id and
I.Insured_Id = IU.Insured_Id and
p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-May-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
p.annual_premium < '1000'
```

Which should return all the records between 12/15/2013 and 05/01/2014 with annual_premium < 1000. The code you included could be modified to work using parentheses thusly:

```
Where
W.Insured_Id = P.Insured_Id and
P.Insured_Id = I.Insured_Id and
I.Insured_Id = IU.Insured_Id and
(
    (
        p.expiration_date > to_date ('30-Apr-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
        p.expiration_date < to_date ('16-Dec-2014','dd-mm-yyyy')
    )
    or
    (
        p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
        p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-May-2014','dd-mm-yyyy')
    )
    or
    (
        p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
        p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-Jan-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')
    )
    or
    (
        p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and
        p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-Jan-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')
    )
)
and p.annual_premium < '1000'
```

However, that's going to include a bunch of records compared to what you requested. Simplified, this code works out to being the same as this, due to overlapping dates:

```
Where
W.Insured_Id = P.Insured_Id and
P.Insured_Id = I.Insured_Id and
I.Insured_Id = IU.Insured_Id and
p.expiration_date > to_date ('15-Dec-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
p.expiration_date < to_date ('01-Jan-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') and
p.annual_premium < '1000'
```

Comment: This is great, and I am sorry, I think trying to go through this I confused myself even further (apparently not difficult to do). What I needed to be returned was all policies between 12-16-2013 and 4-31-2014 under 1000 and then everything else throughout the year. I was able to solve it with the help of your answers! Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround `OR` clauses with bracketes and use between brackets:

> (... OR ...) and (... OR ...) ...

Comment: Any chance you could throw them where they are supposed to go? I tried to do it on my side unsuccessfully. Thank you again!